# Save File.path in user using mongodb and multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to link a image to a user using a file.path in multer, but it just doesent save the photo
here is my code:

```
router.post('/register',upload.single('profilepic'), async (req, res) =>{
 const {email}  = req.body

 try{
        if(req.file != undefined){
            const post = await Post.create({
                name: req.file.originalname,
                size: req.file.size,
                key: req.file.filename,
                photo: req.file.path,
                url: ''
            })
            console.log(req.file)
            //console.log(req.body)
           
        
            if (await User.findOne({ email }))
                return res.status(400).send({error: 'User already exists'})
            
            
            const user =  await User.create(req.body)
            user.password = undefined
            user.photo = req.file.path
            return res.send({
                user,
                token: generateToken({ id: user.id})
            })
```

As you can see Im passing the user.photo as the req.file.path, but it doesent really save it it return me the path whe I upload but it doesent save, here is my user model:

```
const UserScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true,

    },
 
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        unique :true,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    photo:{
        type:String,
        required: false,
        select:true
    },
   
    password:{
        type :String,
        required: true,
        select:false
    },
    passwordResetToken:{
        type: String,
        select: false

    },
    passwordResetExpires:{
        type: Date,
        select: false
    },
    createdAt:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add photo before creating user like

```
req.body.photo = req.file.path;
const user =  await User.create(req.body);
user.password = undefined
return res.send({
  user,
  token: generateToken({ id: user.id}) // user.id or user._id ?
})
```